# How to loop thru divs and add +1 for every div in the loop

Tags: javascript

I  have this row of divs with classname `get-item hourrow`

I want to loop through them and add 1 in the first div and 2 in the second div etc..

```
get_hour = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-item hourrow');
console.log(get_hour)
for(let i = 0; i < get_hour.length; i++){
  get_hour.innerHTML+= "hour" + i;
  console.log(get_hour.innerHTML)
}
```

the result of this loop is

```
> undefinedhour0 local.js:116 undefinedhour0hour1 local.js:116
> undefinedhour0hour1hour2 local.js:116 undefinedhour0hour1hour2hour3
> local.js:116 undefinedhour0hour1hour2hour3hour4 local.js:116
> undefinedhour0hour1hour2hour3hour4hour5
```

Comment: `get_hour` is a bunch of elements, inside the loop you need `get_hour[i]` to access the element. On the other hand you seem to want to grab a single element, so you need to append `[0]` to the first line (and read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) for the commands you're using) Weirdly, your code is treating `get_hour` both as single element and list of elements at the same time.

Comment: Or you can call as `Array.prototype.forEach.call(get_hour, function(el) { el.innerHTML += 'your stuff' })`.

Comment: you forgot to select the element with `[i]`... `get_hour[i].innerHTML+= "hour" + i;`

Comment: In your first sentence you mention `get-item hourrow`. In the code you access something else.

Comment: indeed forgot the [i] thanks a lot guys !

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll(".hourrow")].forEach((div,i) => div.innerHTML += 
 \` hour${(i+1)}\`)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem.

```
   get_hour = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-item hourrow'); //this returns an array get_hour

   // so you must change the innerHTML of the div at get_hour[i] :

    for(let i = 0; i < get_hour.length; i++){
      get_hour[i].innerHTML+= "hour" + i;
      console.log(get_hour[i].innerHTML)
    }
```

Please provide more details for a better help.

Comment: This is just a typo type error; please don't post answers for these.

Comment: Ok. but why ? @ChrisG

Comment: Because typos are a close reason, for one. The other reason is that stack overflow is supposed to be a repository of useful questions and answers that benefit more people than just the OP; a typo issue doesn't help anybody else and is thus not suitable to permanently remain here. SO doesn't work like other question and answer sites; it's basically a huge FAQ so duplicates and OT questions are rigorously closed and removed.